# Is there any linux distribution that comes with python 2.6 yet?

Tags: python, linux

I've heard ubuntu 9.4 will but it's still in alpha. Are there any stable distros that come with python 2.6 or at least don't depend on it so much so reinstalling python won't break anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arch Linux - http://www.archlinux.org/

Comment: Yeah. I didn't think of that one. It's one of the best distros I've used. Thanx.

Answer (score 6):

You can install python 2.6 in Ubuntu 8.10 just fine.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make altinstall --prefix=/usr/local
```

Then just run python with:

```
python2.6
```

If you want to use it in a shebang line, just use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

Your scripts will still work when Jaunty 9.04 is around with native python2.6.

Comment: will python2.6 setup.py on packages with c extensions like psycopg and twisted work fine?

Comment: @Vasil: yes, provided the extension works on python 2.6;

Comment: stow is your friend with source packages. Seriously, do a Google search.

Answer (score 4):

openSUSE 11.1 ships Python 2.6 as standard.

Answer (score 3):

Distrowatch will prob be your best place to look it has lots of details comparing different distros.

http://distrowatch.com/

Karl

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Python 2.6 is available in the Portage tree for Gentoo, but it's hardmasked (that doesn't really count as stable) because apparently there are some programs that don't work with it. My guess is that if you had Gentoo, you could install Python 2.6 and get it to work, but it might not be smart to make it the default version (i.e. you'd want to keep Python 2.5 around as well).

Comment: I run gentoo on one of my servers. But I'm looking for something that doesn't take 3 days to install everything I need, because I'm setting up a desktop system.

Comment: Fair enough, it is kind of a pain to wait for things to compile (although I will note: I use Gentoo on all my computers - 2 laptops and a server - because it's great for development)

Comment: Gentoo would be fine if things always compiled. But when I'm trying to install an Office Suite on my rockin' Pentium 4 machine, sometimes things don't work. Probably my fault, but I just lose patience. :p

Comment: If i Had to guess, Python 2.6 is most likely hardmasked because portage is written in python, and if portage is broken, then your entire gentoo system is broken.

Comment: You always can restore it with Gentoo boot CD or with any live CD with kernel 2.6.*

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6.5 is available in [Fedora Rawhide](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/development/), but Rawhide is the development branch, so that probably doesn't fit your description of "stable" (despite being remarkably stable).  It doesn't seem to have made it into Fedora 10 yet, and I don't know if it will or not.  It will be in Fedora 11 for sure -- you can get a prerelease of it already, which should be more stable than Rawhide.  Alternately, you should be able to grab the package from the prerelease or Rawhide and install it under Fedora 10 without issue, I think.

Comment: 2.6, not 2.6.5. And it would be 2.6.1 but for the runtime linking errors. Oh, and DON'T take the Rawhide package and install it under 10 unless you like having a broken system.